# Lazy load components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-performance

I'm working on a legacy react-app, hence lot of pieces cannot be reasoned about but simply accepted.

So, I have a couple of components that load a lot of dependencies and are obviously not important for the first render. Hence, I tried the following:

```
  const HeavyComp = lazy(() => import("HeavyComponent.jsx");

  function Home() {
    return <div>
      <HeavyComp />
    </div>
  }
```

As a result of this, `HeavyComponent` is loaded as part of main bundle and but is only visible after that component is loaded. This helps by breaking scripting time but FCP is still far away.

So, I tried the following:

```
 

  function Home() {
    const [ heavyComponent. setHeavyComponent ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      setHeavyComponent(
        lazy(() => import("HeavyComponent.jsx")
      );
    }, []);



    return <div>
      {
        heavyComponent && <heavyComponent />
      }
    </div>
  }
```

I thought this'd help but same as before, FCP was still delayed until `heavyComponent` was downloaded, parsed and rendered. So my only option was to make it async using `setTimeout` or better `requestIdleCallback`.

Is this the best solution or is there something better?

Comment: what is `FCP`? can you clarify that first ?

Comment: ok, you might be looking for something called `Suspense`, look for the react concurrent programming, https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Comment: This works for components that don't have to be rendered immediately. For example, ```{
        isTrue()? <div>True</div>: <Header />
      }```. In this case Header is not downloaded at all, its only downloaded when needed,.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that with FCP you are referring to "first content paint". The best option is to use the `Suspense` component. With it, you can add a fallback loader component (`<Spinner />` in this example).

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const HeavyComp = lazy(() => import("HeavyComponent.jsx");

function Home() {
    return <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
         <HeavyComp />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
}
```

[React concurrent-mode documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)

Comment: This works for components that don't have to be rendered immediately. For example, ```{         isTrue()? <div>True</div>: <Header />       }```. In this case Header is not downloaded at all, its only downloaded when needed.
If the component is to be rendered immediately your FCP is after header is downloaded and executed.